# Enhancement of existing primefaces 2.2.1 components

Tags: primefaces

I've a requirement to enhance the exixting primefaces 2.2.1 components with more look and feel like a watermark with calendar and so on. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only enhancements you wish you make are visual or style related then you can create or modify your own Primefaces Theme utilizing the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Information on to apply your new theme to a Primefaces project can be found in the [Primefaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try that out. It also requires me to add additional scroll bars to the datatable and so on. How can that be done?

Comment: @Deepika, Wow... those sound like pretty specific requirements :(  If you have such specific requirements then Primefaces or any third-party JSF component library is not a good choice IMHO.  You will probably be better off writing custom JSF components from scratch, but in case you are interested (or crazy) I would look at the YUI data table component as this component was borrowed for use in the Primefaces Data Table.  Good luck.

Comment: That sounds quite complex.:( Its an immediate requirement. So it would be difficult to modify the primefaces data tables is what you say..

Comment: @Deepika, I took a brief look at the Primefaces dataTable code and it is enormously complex, and is by far the most complex third-party JSF component I have encountered thus far.  Immediate requirement?  You have a tough client.  Personally I would just use JQuery and PHP because what they want is so custom.